# software development: Implantation vs Implementation

Tags: implementation

In software development, implantation is the same that implementation?

I read some articles and implementation describe the phase where you coding the application. I understand that implantation is similar to deployment

Comment: I've encountered that term a few times in system analysis classes, and other classes that deal with the SDLC. Most often it is simply a typo where implementation was meant to be said. Those times its not it just means deployment.

Answer (score 2):

I checked numerous references on software engineering that I have in my office. I could not find the term implantation in any of them.  Implantation, it seems, is a common biological term.

The IEEE Computer Society does not define implantation in my 2003 copy of their "Compilation of Software Engineering Terms from Existing Sources."

The IEEE defines implementation as "(1) The process of translating a design into hardware components, software components, or both. (2) The result of the process in [IEEE Std. 610.12-1990]"

Comment: Mike Jablonski , I'm not sure if "implantation" is the proper translation of "implantación" (Spanish). In Spain and some spanish speaking countries, the software development projects use this term. Some links: 

http://www.sav.us.es/pixelbit/pixelbit/articulos/n34/12.pdf

http://ocw.uoc.edu/informatica-tecnologia-y-multimedia/implantacion-de-sistemas-de-software-libre/Course_listing

http://www.informatica-hoy.com.ar/software-erp/Implantacion-de-un-software-ERP.php

http://www.oei.es/salactsi/254-2004.pdf

http://sedici.unlp.edu.ar/bitstream/handle/10915/20124/Documento_completo.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: @PatricioBonilla  Thank you for your comment.  I looked at the link you provided. My Spanish is poor so I was only able to read the English abstract about the article.  It makes sense that the translation of the word from Spanish to English is the issue here.